# Canon Maxify MB2050 driver install

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Good afternoon peeps,

To set the scene, I am really proud to have converted my small business network from a Windows - IT support requiring, slow as hell, problematic, frustrating and generally rubbish system to a Ubuntu - working, robust, switches on in seconds and reliable network! Its been this way for over two years and we use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

HOWEVER

Every time we want to do something simple like add a bloody printer its me who has to go to the geek side and does it really have to be so difficult with sudo this and sudo that!??!

My secretary brought the above printer and I cannot for the life of me get it to just work as a printer let alone a scanner and I am worried that its just not possible despite the printers brilliant write up and price.

Please can anyone help, with reasonably basic instructions. I am a data network installer and I'm pretty confident with computers but don't geek me out and thanks to anyone who gives me a minute to respond.

Regards

Lee

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and went to the canon support site and searched for a linux driver. I downloaded the debian package (cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz) and unzipped it. By double clicking on the package file (cnijfilter2_5.00-1_i386.deb) I installed the file via the Ubuntu software center. (no sudo this or sudo that) After the installation I  went to the system settings and added the printer (after searching for a network printer). Now the drivers were chosen from the system automatically.

I hope this helps.

Regards
Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the above answer and address the scanner issue, our Canon MB2320 works using the same printer driver mentioned by Konstantin in another answer.  If you download the Linux scangear utility from the same [website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/small-office-home-office-printers/mb2320), it provides basic scanning functionality.

At the time I installed the device, the scanning functionality was not supported by the version of `xsane` included in my Ubuntu 14.04 install.  However, by installing the daily `sane` builds from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git)

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu trusty main
```

all functionality of `xsane` was obtained, except for use of the document feeder (the document feeder does work with the scangear utility from Canon).